# XML Serde for Hadoop/Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I used JSONSerde to process huge amounts of JSON data stored on S3 using Amazon EMR. One of my clients has a requirement to process massive XML data but I couldn't find any XML Serde to use with HIVE.

Have you folks processed XML with hive? I would appreciate your suggestions and comments regarding this before I start building my own XML Serde.

Comment: You should be able to build an XML serde that is very similar to the JSON serde.

Comment: Yes, but I am surprised that XML processing is not a common use case and one doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for XML parsing serde in hive ---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE XYZ(
X STRING, 
Y STRING, 
Z ARRAY<STRING>
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.X"="/XX/@X",
"column.xpath.Y"="/YY/@Y"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/XXX' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<xml start",
"xmlinput.end"="</xml end>"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to download the xmlserde is 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/ibm/spss/hive/serde2/xml/hivexmlserde/1.0.0.0/hivexmlserde-1.0.0.0.jar

Put this jar file in path /usr/lib/hive/lib

Once you done with this, you can use this xml serde:

```
   CREATE TABLE xml_bank(customer_id STRING, income BIGINT, demographics 
   map<string,string>, financial map<string,string>)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "column.xpath.customer_id"="/record/@customer_id",
   "column.xpath.income"="/record/income/text()",
   "column.xpath.demographics"="/record/demographics/*",
   "column.xpath.financial"="/record/financial/*"
    )
    TBLPROPERTIES (
    "xmlinput.start"="<record customer",
    "xmlinput.end"="</record>"
    );
```